# Why NOT use optionals in Swift?

Tags: swift, option-type

I was reading up on how to program in Swift, and the concept of optionals bugged me a little bit. Not really in terms of why to use optionals, that makes sense, but more so as to in what case would you not want to use optionals. From what I understand, an optional just allows an object to be set to nil, so why would you not want that feature? Isn't setting an object to nil the way you tell ARC to release an object? And don't most of the functions in Foundation and Cocoa return optionals? So outside of having to type an extra character each time to refer to an object, is there any good reason NOT to use an optional in place of a regular type?

Comment: "why would you not want that feature?" [Listen to Tony Hoare](http://www.infoq.com/presentations/Null-References-The-Billion-Dollar-Mistake-Tony-Hoare). You might learn something about the history of CS, too, which is more important than you might think.

Comment: The point is not necessarily to avoid nil values *anywhere* in code, but to be more explicit about exactly where in the code you know that values *cannot* be nil.

Comment: *"Isn't setting an object to nil the way you tell ARC to release an object?"* It's one way to release an object, but far from the only way. And it typically isn't needed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are tons of reasons to NOT use optional. The main reason: You want to express that a value MUST be available. For example, when you open a file, you want the file name to be a string, not an optional string. Using `nil` as filename simply makes no sense.

I will consider two main use cases: Function arguments and function return values.

For function arguments, the following holds: If the argument needs to be provided, option should not be used. If handing in *nothing* is okay and a valid (documented!) input, then hand in an optional.

For function return values returning no optional is especially nice: You promise the caller that he will receive an object, not either an object or *nothing*. When you do not return an optional, the caller knows that he may use the value right away instead of checking for null first.

For example, consider a factory method. Such method should always return an object, so why should you use optional here? There are a lot of examples like this.

Actually, most APIs should rather use non-optionals instead of optionals. Most of the time, simply passing/receiving possibly *nothing* is just not what you want. There are rather few cases where nothing is an option.

Each case where optional is used must be thoroughly documented: In which circumstances will a method return nothing? When is it okay to hand nothing to a method and what will the consequences be? A lot of documentation overhead.

Then there is also conciseness: If you use an API that uses optional all over the place, your code will be cluttered with null-checks. Of course, if every use of optional is intentional, then these checks are fine and necessary. However, if the API only uses optional because its author was lazy and was simply using optional all over the place, then the checks are unnecessary and pure boilerplate.

### But beware!

My answer may sound as if the concept of optionals is quite crappy. The opposite is true! By having a concept like optionals, the programmer is able to declare whether handing in/returning nothing is okay. The caller of a function is always aware of that and **the compiler enforces safety**. Compare that to plain old C: You could not declare whether a pointer could be `null`. You could add documentation comments that state whether it may be `null`, but such comments were not enforced by the compiler. If the caller forgot to check a return value for null, you received a segfault. With optionals you can be sure that noone dereferences a `null` pointer anymore.

So in conclusion, a null-safe type system is one of the major advances in modern programming languages.

Comment: Actually I can come up with examples where passing nil as the fileName makes sense, for example, you want a temporary file and you don't care what the name is :)  In general though, your answer is spot on.

Comment: @David: Sure, there may always be such cases where *nothing* has a special meaning. Then, optional is perfectly fine. However, often the opposite is the case.

Answer (score 2):

The original idea of optionals (which existed long before Swift) is to *force* programmer to check value for nil before using it — or to prevent outside code from passing nil where it is not allowed. A huge part of crashes in software, maybe even most of them, happens at address 0x00000000 (or with NullPointerException, or alike) precisely because it is way too easy to forget about nil-pointer scenario. (In 2009, Tony Hoare apologized for inventing null pointers).

Not using optionals is as valid and widespread use case as using them: when the value absolutely can not be missing, there should be non-optional type; when it can, there should be an optional.

But currently, the existing frameworks are written in Obj-C without optionals in mind, so automatically generated bridges between Swift and Obj-C just *have* to take and return optionals, because it is impossible to automatically deeply analyze each method and figure out which arguments and return values should be optionals or not. I'm sure over time Apple will manually fix every case where they got it wrong; right now you should not use those frameworks as an example, because they are definitely not a good one. (For good examples, you could check a popular functional language like Haskell which had optionals since the beginning).